# MVC Custom Attribute routing with City and Country URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to create custom attribute routing in MVC, where I want my URLs like this :

```
www.domain.com/in/best-restaurants-in-india    // FOR COUNTRY INDIA
```

and

```
www.domain.com/in/best-restaurants-in-new-delhi-india  // for COUNTRY INDIA CITY DELHI
```

For this I tried to use this

```
  [Route("{isocountry}/best-restaurants-in-{country}")]
  [Route("{isocountry}/best-restaurants-in-{city}-{country}")]
```

But this gives an ambiguous routing issue

I know this is possible as I have seen other website using same in php, but don't know how to do this is MVC.

Please give the proper idea of implementing this ?

Comment: are these both routes applied to same action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you get the error because when you enter

```
www.domain.com/in/best-restaurants-in-india
```

it matches the route `in-{country}` and you enter

```
www.domain.com/in/best-restaurants-in-new-delhi-india
```

it matches both routs because `delhi-india` is a string and can be both which makes it ambitious.

you can achieve this by applying the `Order` in the route attribute because your routing should be defined from most specific to most generic so your route should be like this

```
 [Route("{isocountry}/best-restaurants-in-{country}",Order = 2)]
 [Route("{isocountry}/best-restaurants-in-{city}-{country}",Order = 1)]
```

first it will check the specific route and then the generically defined route.

Comment: Thanks, @Usman , this worked like charm. Didn't know about the order thing. It will help in other situations also.

Comment: Actually, a route can never be "ambiguous". The first match registered always wins and the rest are ignored. But since by default there is no way to guarantee the order in which routes are registered in MVC, the solution is correct.

Comment: @Usman Check this: There is an exceptional case exists, when you try for Country : antigua-and-barbuda and City : hilton-head-island, this route with order won't work.

Comment: If you try this "domain.com/in/best-restaurants-in-hilton-head-island-antigua-and-barbuda" , It will give you wrong input in city and country , as my city is hilton-head-island and country is antigua-and-barbuda